# Process.Start a console application, input in it then get output in a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console, barcode

I would like to open a simple console application that looks like this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Beginning");
        string smth = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
```

I open it thanks to `Process.Start` in a Form like this :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = myexe;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processInfo;
        process.Start();           
    }
```

I managed to read output using a `StreamReader` and get this into a textbox :

```
Beginning
End
```

But the problem is the program doesn't wait at `Console.ReadLine()`, like it is ignored. And i don't know how to let the user input from keyboard (better if it's directly in the console).

Is there a way to do it ?

**EDIT**

Looks like i wasn't clear enough, sorry.

I'm trying to make a simple Form, with **no control**, able to "react" when i scan a barcode.

Basically, i want the console application to run background so when my barcode is scanned, i can get it as my `output` value :

1. Form "Please scan your barcode"
2. Console app is launched
3. Barcode is scanned
4. Console app close
5. Barcode as `output` value

So `StandardInput` doesn't seems to be the solution for my problem.

That's why i'm asking you if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Well you set `RedirectStandardInput` to true, so now the console app will be expecting you to provide it with the input, rather than it getting it via the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what kind of problem you are facing, but I'm noticing that you aren't utilizing the `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` properties of the `Process` instance (which is what you should be doing after redirecting them). See if the following example helps you.

If you have this console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Beginning");
    var str = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("End: " + str);
}
```

And you invoke it through this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "console_program",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
};
Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = processInfo,
};
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hey!");
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

You will get the `output` value:

```
"Beginning\r\nEnd: Hey!\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read something about `StandardInput`, but that's not what i'm trying to do. I edited my post with more "details"